# how to combine multiple sub-arrays that contain same objects' keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

Can someone help me with this, please? I've spent a long time trying to figure it out.  I have the following format:

```
[
  [{id:'1',venue:'foa',title:'t'},{id:'5',venue:'cs',title:'b'}, ...],
  [{id:'2',venue:'fob',title:'t'},{id:'6',venue:'cs',title:'b'}, ...],    
  [{id:'3',venue:'foc',title:'t'},{id:'7',venue:'cs',title:'b'}, ...],
  [{id:'4',venue:'fod',title:'t'},{id:'8',venue:'cs',title:'b'}, ...]
]
```

what is the simplest way to make it in this format (._underscore preferably):

```
{id:'1',venue:'foa',title:'t'}
{id:'5',venue:'cs',title:'b'}
{id:'2',venue:'fob',title:'t'}
{id:'6',venue:'cs',title:'b'}
{id:'3',venue:'foc',title:'t'}
{id:'7',venue:'cs',title:'b'}
{id:'4',venue:'fod',title:'t'}
{id:'8',venue:'cs',title:'b'}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`flatten()`](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten).

```js
var arr = [[{id:'1',venue:'foa',title:'t'},{id:'5',venue:'cs',title:'b'}],[{id:'2',venue:'fob',title:'t'},{id:'6',venue:'cs',title:'b'}],    [{id:'3',venue:'foc',title:'t'},{id:'7',venue:'cs',title:'b'}],[{id:'4',venue:'fod',title:'t'},{id:'8',venue:'cs',title:'b'}]],
    result = _.flatten(arr);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear enough but if you just want to flatten your array, you can use the below code:

```js
var arr = [
  [{id:'1',venue:'foa',title:'t'},{id:'5',venue:'cs',title:'b'}],
  [{id:'2',venue:'fob',title:'t'},{id:'6',venue:'cs',title:'b'}],   
  [{id:'3',venue:'foc',title:'t'},{id:'7',venue:'cs',title:'b'}],
  [{id:'4',venue:'fod',title:'t'},{id:'8',venue:'cs',title:'b'}]
];

var res = [].concat(...arr);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but here's what you can try using Lodash:

```js
var result = [];

var obj = [
  [{id:'1',venue:'foa',title:'t'},{id:'5',venue:'cs',title:'b'}],
  [{id:'2',venue:'fob',title:'t'},{id:'6',venue:'cs',title:'b'}],    
  [{id:'3',venue:'foc',title:'t'},{id:'7',venue:'cs',title:'b'}],
  [{id:'4',venue:'fod',title:'t'},{id:'8',venue:'cs',title:'b'}]
];

_.each(obj, function(i) {

  _.each(i, function(j) {
    result.push(j);
  });

});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```